# How to get the IP address from a nmap output in XML with an specific vendor using ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, nmap

Using the XML output from [nmap](http://nmap.org/) for the reachable virtual machines running on the host machine - obtained with `nmap -oX output.xml -sP 192.168.2.*`, I'd like to get the IP address of each machine whose vendor matches `QEMU Virtual NIC`. I chose to use Python's [ElementTree XML API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml-tree-and-elements) to do that, but I'm having trouble isolating the **host** elements with the specified **address** elements.

Here it goes a snippet of the XML output to be used:

```
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
<address addr="192.168.2.93" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="52:54:00:E2:17:31" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="1023" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
<address addr="192.168.2.96" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="52:54:00:45:86:8A" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="155" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
<address addr="192.168.2.103" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="52:54:00:61:7A:E5" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="391" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
</host>
```

Using `findall` and the XPath syntax below, I could find the **address** elements which have the wanted vendor attribute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('output.xml')
tree.findall("./host/address/[@vendor='QEMU Virtual NIC']")
```

But what I really want are the **host** elements which own the **address** elements found above, so I can then find the other **address** sub-elements of type "ipv4" for the same host so I can finally have the host IP address. Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve that using *XPath* and *ElementTree*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use ElementTree (and not lxml)

```
>>> [i.get('addr') for i in tree.findall(
...     './host/address[@vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"]/../address[@addrtype="ipv4"]')]
['192.168.2.93', '192.168.2.96', '192.168.2.103']
```

`lxml` is a much better library but if external dependencies are not allowed this will have to do.

Comment: Worked perfectly.. thanks! Now I'll try to completely understand the syntax... it's my first try at this.

Comment: `findall` can process only a small subset xpath.  This works using what you started with, then use `..` to back up one level, then go back down to the specific node with attribute `addrtype="ipv4"` defined.

Answer (score 2):

The hosts:

```
./host[address[@vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"]]
```

The IPv4 addresses:

```
./host[address[@vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"]]/address[@addrtype="ipv4"]/@addr
```

Interactively using `lxml`:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.XML("""<doc><host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
... <address addr="192.168.2.93" addrtype="ipv4"/>
... <address addr="52:54:00:E2:17:31" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
... <hostnames>
... </hostnames>
... <times srtt="1023" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
... </host>
... <host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
... <address addr="192.168.2.96" addrtype="ipv4"/>
... <address addr="52:54:00:45:86:8A" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
... <hostnames>
... </hostnames>
... <times srtt="155" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
... </host>
... <host><status state="up" reason="arp-response"/>
... <address addr="192.168.2.103" addrtype="ipv4"/>
... <address addr="52:54:00:61:7A:E5" addrtype="mac" vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"/>
... <hostnames>
... </hostnames>
... <times srtt="391" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
... </host></doc>""")
>>> doc.xpath('./host[address[@vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"]]')
[<Element host at 0xb72c0af4>, <Element host at 0xb72c0b1c>, <Element host at 0xb72c0b44>]
>>> doc.xpath('./host[address[@vendor="QEMU Virtual NIC"]]/address[@addrtype="ipv4"]/@addr')
['192.168.2.93', '192.168.2.96', '192.168.2.103']
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I couldn't get it to work with ElementTree (I get a `SyntaxError: invalid predicate` doing `findall` with those arguments. I'll try to learn from these examples so I get used to this XPath syntax.

Comment: Note that `findall` only process a subset of the full xpath syntax, and the full xpath syntax is supported by `lxml.xpath`, not `ElementTree.findall`.